# Can i use Entity Framework for Non-DB results from a web service?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, entity-framework, dynamics-crm

I am working on a project where different data is presented via a set of web services.  These web services are a front end to MS Dynamics CRM.  What the services are returning is essentially a class that has an Entity (a CRM Entity) in a paged data wrapper.

```
[DataContract]
public class PagedData<T>
{
    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue=true)]
    public T[] Items { get; set; }
    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue=true)]
    public int PageNumber { get; set; }
    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue=true)]
    public int PageSize { get; set; }
    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue=true)]
    public int TotalCount { get; set; }
}
```

My app will use a web page with drop down lists to fill in the values that will go into these services.  At the same time, I will be retrieving data to populate the drop down lists via these services.

I've seen articles on here about producing web services using Entity Framework, including links to [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/orm-9780596520281-01-14.aspx), but i have not seen much on consuming into or using Entity Framework to create a facade to a web service.

Any ideas what i should do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entity Framework works on any Data source that has a " EntityFramework provider"

[EF providers](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Rebuilding%20EF%20providers%20for%20EF6)

Providers for major Databases are available.

If the source data in memory Objects, then there is no need to Use EntityFramework.
You can simply use LInq to the in memory lists/collections.

So your web page can make a WCF call to get a result. This result can be accessed in memory
when it returns.  I see no need for EF in that scenario. Just LINQ away

Comment: Yeah, i was probably too tired when i wrote that one.  As I slept on it, i realized the same thing.  I can use Web API as my "facade" with MVC5 as my "front end".